# Points-in-a-plane from HackerRank

Tags: algorithm

I've been struggling with this problem for days now, making no progress:

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/points-in-a-plane

I've tried a greedy exhaustive solution, where I draw a line between each pair of points, then start to eliminate the lines in descending order based on the number of points they cross. Unfortunately, there is at least one case where this approach produces suboptimal results:

For ease of discussion, I will call lines "longer" or "shorter", based on how many points they include. The greedy algorithm is simply to eliminate lines in order of descending length.

Suppose we have a set of N longer lines, and another set of M shorter lines. Our greedy algorithm will eliminate the long lines first. But what if every single point of the long lines is also included in a short line?  In that case,our initial elimination of the N longer line was a waste, since we would have gotten those lines "for free" had we just eliminated the shorter lines. Specifically, our greedy approach will require N + M eliminations, where we could have cleared all points in just M steps.

The simplest example input demonstrating this is:

```
(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 4), (3, 3)
(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0)
(0,-1), (1,-2), (2,-4), (3,-3)
```

As you can see, we have a line of length 4 running along the X axis, and 4 shorter lines of length 3 perpendicular to it. Our greedy algorithm will first eliminate the longest line, after which there will be 8 sets of points remaining, with no more than 2 of them collinear. Eliminating those will thus take 4 steps, for a total 5. We could eliminate all points in 4 steps, if we just started from the shorter perpendicular lines instead.

Could someone provide at least a hint at the general body of knowledge required to approach this? I solved many other HackerRank questions, but can't make any headway with this one.

Comment: The category on hackerrank should give it away: it's a graph problem. To be precise, a matching problem. For the set of `n` points, consider all `n(n-1)` lines through a pair of points (if some points are collinear you might have less lines). Create a graph as follows: one set of vertices are the input points (one vertex per point) and one set of vertices are the lines (one vertex per line). There is an edge between a point-vertex and a line-vertex if the line covers that point. Now, you have a standard matching problem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)).

Comment: @Heuster: thanks, I definitely should learn more graph theory.

Comment: Have you tried proving why `k*(n-k)+\binom{k,2}` should work?

Answer (score 0):

In what follows the use of `k` is to denote the number of points in a given line. The greedy algorithm you suggested where you order the line removal by decreasing `k` values is incorrect as you rightly pointed out with counter-example. Instead, try ordering by decreasing `k * (n-k) + \binom{k, 2}`, where `n` is the number of points remaining. If you use this you will always find the minimum number of turns `T` as requested for the first part of the solution.  It is relatively easy to prove this, and I leave it as an exercise.